# datatable table format export to pdf

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

my target is to export my table into pdf in the same format. Currently, when I am exporting my table to PDF, the format is not the same in my view.

**This is my table:**
[image]

**This is what happens after I export it into PDF**

[image]

Any guide or help will be appreciated. Thank you so much and have a nice day

**View:**

```
<table id="notable" class="table test table-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth text-nowrap" style="width:100%; ">
                      
                          <thead>             
                            <tr>
                            <th>NO.</th> 
                              <th>ENTRYNAME</th>                      
                              <th>WB</th>
                              <th>LB</th>
                              <th>WT</th>
                              <th>NO.</th>
                              <th>#</th>
                              <th>ENTRY NAME</th>
                              <th>WB</th>
                              <th>LB</th>
                              <th>WT</th>
                              <th>DIFF</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                  <tbody>
   
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

**Script:**

```
var no=$('#notable').DataTable({ 
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        'pageLength':20,  
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]], 
        buttons: [
            'print', 'csv', 'copy', 'excel', 'pdfHtml5'
        ],
       
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.    
        "order": [], //Initial no order.
        
 
        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('controller/function')?>",
            "type": "POST",
             "data": function ( data ) {
                data.eventID = $('#eventID').val();

                }
        },
 
        rowGroup: {
            dataSrc: 1
        },
      
        
             columnDefs: [{
    "defaultContent": "-",
    "targets": "_all",
     "width": "1%", "targets": 0
  },


  
  ],
        
    
 
    });
```

**Controller:**

```
public function matchlist()
        {
            
            $count = 1;
            
            $list = $this->repo->get_datatables();
            $data = array();
            $no = $_POST['start'];
            $countnew = '1';
            $check_arr = array();
         
                
                
               
            foreach ($list as $person1) {
                $no++;
                if($person1->weightM>$person1->weightW){
                    $sum=$person1->weightM-$person1->weightW;
                }else{
                    $sum=$person1->weightW-$person1->weightM;
                }
                
                
               
                if(!empty($check_arr) && !in_array($person1->handlerM, $check_arr))  {
                    $countnew = 1;
                }
               
                $row = array();
              
                
                $row[]=  $countnew++;
                $row[] = $person1->handlerM ;
                $row[] = $person1->wingBandM;
                $row[] = $person1->legBandM;
                $row[] = $person1->weightM;
                $row[] = $person1->fightNumber;
                $row[] = $person1->handlerIDW;
                $row[] = $person1->handlertestW;
                $row[] = $person1->wingBandW;
                $row[] = $person1->legBandW;
                $row[] = $person1->weightW;
                $row[] = $sum;
                
                $data[] = $row;
                $check_arr[] = $person1->handlerM;
            }
            
            $output = array(
                "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                "recordsTotal" => $this->repo->count_all(),
                "recordsFiltered" => $this->repo->count_filtered(),
                "data" => $data,
            );
            //output to json format
            echo json_encode($output);
    
        
        }
```